Angular V19 ng build --configuration production -- dist folder tree
I have created a new Angular application using version 19 without SSR enabled. When I try to run the application from the Visual Studio terminal. where as I couldn't be able to deploy the code to iis.
enter image description here
Following options used while creation of Angular application:
enter image description here
When I try to build the application using the following command: ng build --configuration production
After successful execution, I can see the following folders under Dist Folder -> application folder name
enter image description here
Here the Angular.json file configuration:
enter image description here
Issue : I am unable to server the Angular application from Windows iis. After copying the dist folder content to the iis application folder below the error message.
enter image description here
And also I have added web.config file in order to run the angular application from iis.
Can you please help me on this?
Please provide any addition changes required from our end to work from windows iis.

Please ref : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/58896

have you checked the content of the dist directory ?

You need to copy the folder dist/<project-name>/browser to your server.
